# Is there an example code in Python for creating dropdown / popup menus using PGU?

Tags: python, user-interface, menu, pygame, pgu

I'm a very beginner programmer looking for ways to create drop-down GUI objects. I would like a menu to drop down at wherever part of the screen the user right clicks, and make the menu disappear when user left clicks outside of it.

I would prefer that the number of options in the drop down menu depends on the place that the user has clicked, but if there are no modules that can accommodate this, that's okay.

I am using the PGU module for Pygame package, and I'm thinking of looking into Ocemp module if PGU doesn't work out. That being said I'm also open to any other packages that can easily accomplish what I want to do.

What I am really in need of is some example codes relating to what I want to do; I would be very grateful for anything along the lines of a link, some pasted code, or any suggestions and tips.

Thanks!

Comment: Related question if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302973/making-popup-windows-in-pygame-with-pgu

Comment: There's a lot of examples at http://pygame.org/tags/pgu , http://pygame.org/tags/gui , and the toplevel: http://pygame.org/tags/